# is there any way to interpose the instantiation process of autofac?

Tags: c#, filter, autofac, instantiation

I have three class declaration like above

```
 [Plug("hello")]
 public class Plug1 : IPlug{}
 [Plug("hello")]
 public class Plug2 : IPlug{}
 [Plug("world")]
 public class Plug3 : IPlug{}
```

When i use `container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IPlug>>()` to resolve, I get all instance which implements the `IPlug` interface, however, I want to get the first and second (or by the world, which the instance was tagged by attribute `Plug("hello")`).

Is there any way to achieve it ?

I would like to avoid using

```
container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IPlug>>()
         .Where(t => t.FirstAttribute<Plug>() != null 
                     && t.FirstAttribute<Plug>().Id == "Hello")
```

I always feel it is not the best practice as result of the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many way to do what you want.

The easiest way would be to register your type as named registration

```
builder.RegisterType<Plug1>().As<IPlug>().WithMetadata("plug", "hello");
builder.RegisterType<Plug2>().As<IPlug>().WithMetadata("plug", "hello");
builder.RegisterType<Plug3>().As<IPlug>().WithMetadata("plug", "world");
```

you can also use the attribute to register these types :

```
builder.RegisterType<Plug1>()
       .As<IPlug>()
       .WithMetadata("plug", typeof(Plug1).FirstAttribute<Plug>().?Id ?? "Default");
```

Then you will be able to get all named `IPlug` registration using an `IEnumerable<Meta<IPlug>>` :

```
container.Resolve<IEnumerable<Meta<IPlug>>>()
         .Where(m => m.Metadata["plug"] as String == "hello")
         .Select(m => m.Value);
```

If you don't want to filter at runtime but during IoC root composition and `IEnumerable<IPlug>` will always resolve a filtered `IEnumerable<IPlug>` then you can override the `IEnumerable<IPlug>` registration :

```
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IEnumerable<Meta<IPlug>>>()
                       .Where(m => m.Metadata["plug"] as String ==  "hello")
                       .Select(m => m.Value))
       .As<IEnumerable<IPlug>>();
```